# Storing an image and display it when I launch the app again

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hey guys, I have some questions would like to ask:

- I wanna ask how can I store the image so that next time when the user open the app and the app will show the image which previously he just choose it?
- The image will be taken from either Photo Library or Camera Photo so I don't think I can get the path for the photo and store only the path right?

Anyway I can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you convert that image into NSData And store that NSData in plist file at  applicationDidFinishLaunching.

NSData *Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(your image, 1);

Answer (score 0):

probably cache the image in your app's documents folder(or nsuserdefaults), store the path in nsuserdefaults and load it up in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: but what is the path for image? because that path is in photo library or camera library?

Comment: if you can get the image you want into a uiview then just render the context and save it as nsdata, dont worry about the path. basically you're making a new image so you'll be breaking any link to the original if you need it then you'll probably have to think of something else.